# The property 'EntityKeyMember.Value' could not be mapped because it is of type 'object'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got the following problem when I tried to get Data from my Database with Entity Framework

```
'The property 'EntityKeyMember.Value' could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'
```

My class is generated by an entity developer and looks like this:

```
public partial class User : EntityObject    {

    public static User CreateUser(int iD, string firstName, int account, string userName)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.ID = iD;
        user.FirstName = firstName;
        user.Account = account;
        user.UserName = userName;
        return user;
    }

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public virtual int ID
    {
        get
        {
            int value = _ID;
            OnGetID(ref value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ID != value)
            {
              OnIDChanging(ref value);
              ReportPropertyChanging("ID");
              _ID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
              ReportPropertyChanged("ID");
              OnIDChanged();
          }
        }
    }
    private int _ID;
    partial void OnGetID(ref int value);
    partial void OnIDChanging(ref int value);
    partial void OnIDChanged();

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public virtual string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            string value = _FirstName;
            OnGetFirstName(ref value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_FirstName != value)
            {
              OnFirstNameChanging(ref value);
              ReportPropertyChanging("FirstName");
              _FirstName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
              ReportPropertyChanged("FirstName");
              OnFirstNameChanged();
          }
        }
    }
    private string _FirstName;
    partial void OnGetFirstName(ref string value);
    partial void OnFirstNameChanging(ref string value);
    partial void OnFirstNameChanged();

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute()]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public virtual string? LastName
    {
        get
        {
            string? value = _LastName;
            OnGetLastName(ref value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_LastName != value)
            {
              OnLastNameChanging(ref value);
              ReportPropertyChanging("LastName");
              _LastName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
              ReportPropertyChanged("LastName");
              OnLastNameChanged();
          }
        }
    }
    private string? _LastName;
    partial void OnGetLastName(ref string? value);
    partial void OnLastNameChanging(ref string? value);
    partial void OnLastNameChanged();

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public virtual int Account
    {
        get
        {
            int value = _Account;
            OnGetAccount(ref value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Account != value)
            {
              OnAccountChanging(ref value);
              ReportPropertyChanging("Account");
              _Account = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
              ReportPropertyChanged("Account");
              OnAccountChanged();
          }
        }
    }
    private int _Account;
    partial void OnGetAccount(ref int value);
    partial void OnAccountChanging(ref int value);
    partial void OnAccountChanged();

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public virtual string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            string value = _UserName;
            OnGetUserName(ref value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_UserName != value)
            {
              OnUserNameChanging(ref value);
              ReportPropertyChanging("UserName");
              _UserName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
              ReportPropertyChanged("UserName");
              OnUserNameChanged();
          }
        }
    }
    private string _UserName;
    partial void OnGetUserName(ref string value);
    partial void OnUserNameChanging(ref string value);
    partial void OnUserNameChanged();

}
```

I create a new DataContext to connect to the database:

```
public class FinanceDataContext : DbContext
{
    static readonly string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=databaseName;password=;";

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    }

    
}
```

In the following code snipped the exception occurs when trying to load users:

```
using (var context = new FinanceDataContext())
{
    var userList = context.User.ToList<User>();
}
```

In the following code snipped the exception occurs when trying to load users:

```
using (var context = new FinanceDataContext())
{
    var userList = context.User.ToList<User>();
}
```

I tried to map this class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);
        entity.Property(e => e.UserName);
        entity.Property(e => e.FirstName);
        entity.Property(e => e.Account);
        entity.Property(e => e.LastName);
        entity.ToTable("User");
    });
    
}
```